# WebView вообще ни в какую не запускает локальный javascript

Tags: android, android-webview

У меня есть вэбвью, и я загружаю index.html с asset. В index.html через  указывается js файл, находящийся в всё том же каталоге asset. Также я пробовал просто поместить джаваскрипт код в тег . Джаваскрипт ни как не работает. Я перепробовал уже все возможные комбинации кодов, но ничего не получается, то есть сам index.html загружается но джаваскрипт не выполняется. С интернета тот же index.html и js файл работают корректно.

MainActivity.java

```
 package com.example.myapplication;

 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
 import android.net.NetworkInfo;
 import android.os.Build;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.WindowManager;
 import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
 import android.webkit.WebSettings;
 import android.webkit.WebView;
 import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

 import com.example.myapplication.R;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    }

    WebView myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if( activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected())
    {myWebView.loadUrl("http://с_интернета");}
    else
    {myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");}

}
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapplication">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Запускаю на Samsung Galaxy Core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем долго пытался это решить, проблема была в самом джаваскрипте. Он всё-таки работал и грузился но, по-моему из-за строки `var arr=[];` , происходила типо ошибка дже эс и код не выполнялся, хотя с интернета выполнялся.

Для кто столкнулся\столкнётся с подобной проблемой вот код, который 100% запускает джаваскрипт во вэбвью

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.JsPromptResult;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.myapplication.R;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{

WebView myWebView;

public String ReadFromfile(String fileName) {
    StringBuilder ReturnString = new StringBuilder();
    InputStream fIn = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    BufferedReader input = null;
    try {
        fIn = getAssets().open(fileName);
        isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
        input = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = "";
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            ReturnString.append(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (isr != null)
                isr.close();
            if (fIn != null)
                fIn.close();
            if (input != null)
                input.close();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.getMessage();
        }
    }
    return ReturnString.toString();
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    }

    myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {


        }
    });

    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if( activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected())
    {myWebView.loadUrl("http://сайт.имя");}
    else
    {

        myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", ReadFromfile("index.html"), "text/html", "utf-8", null);

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

    }

}


}
```

Comment: Манифест оставить таким же как в вопросе. Дже эс и джава - бред, си - рулит

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Распишите подробнее свой ответ. Он может помочь другим пользователям. Понятно, что нужно включить localStorage, но тем не менее...